# Rails Paperclip,How to create a thumbnail without stretching a user's FB profile photo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

My app allows for FB Connect. When you connect we grab your FB profile photo and create a thumbnail using paperclip.

Right now users are angry that there photos are being stretched. We are using the setting:

```
:styles => { :thumb => "100x100>" }
```

What is the preferred setting to create a thumbnail and not stretch? Something that maintains the aspect ratio and likely positions at the top as to not cut off a person's head?

Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I do not see a problem, are you sure that you are using the correct helper in your view, e.g. `<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
`

Comment: In my controller I'm setting the image as a background on a div with a fixed width and height of 35px. Which is why I need to find a way to make a thumb of 100x100 that maintains the aspect ratio of the orig photo. ideas?

Comment: you want to store in 100x100, but are displaying it in a div that is 35px high? These settings look correct to me, if you are not calling it like @topek is suggesting, you are likely stretching it with CSS when setting it as the background image..

Comment: @Rabbott correct, I am stretching it with CSS. how can I maintain an aspect ratio to prevent streching?

Comment: The problem here is if the image is 1x4 ratio wise. I need to extract a square profile without stretching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have an easier time doing all your image manipulation as part of the Paperclip processing. Try

```
:styles => {:square => "35x35#" }
```

and then you can render that image directly into your div with no css.